# how to pass other arguments besides flags

Tags: bash, shell, sh, getopt, getopts

I am trying to execute my file by passing in an absolute path as the first argument ($1). I also want to add flags from that absolute path onward, but i do not know how to tell optargs to start counting from $2 forward since if i pass in the absolute path as the $1 it seems to break the getopts loop.

I'm gussing i have to implement a shift for the first argument in the following code:

```
while getopts :lq flag; do
case $flag in
l) echo "executing -l flag"
;;
q) echo "executing -q flag"
;;
esac
done
```

I'm not sure how to approach this. Any tips are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Provide sample command and expected output. It helps to answer better.

Comment: Note that in general, options should come *before* arguments; this is POSIX-specified behavior. GNU allowing positional arguments to come first is an extension, and a rather unfortunate one as it makes parsing ambiguous (requiring users to add the `--` end-of-options sigil to prevent arguments that start with dashes to be incorrectly parsed as options) in cases where it wouldn't be otherwise. See section 12.2, by the end of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getopts` does, indeed, stop processing the arguments when it sees the first non-option argument. For what you want, you can explicitly shift the first argument if it is not an option. Something like

```
if [[ $1 != -* ]]; then
    path=$1
    shift
fi

while getopts :lq flag; do
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the options before file argument (i.e. absolute path).
Many standard bash commands follow the same practice.

Example :

```
wc -wl ~/sample.txt
ls -lR ~/sample_dir
```

So if you follow the above practice, your code goes like this. 
This code works even if options are not provided. 
In general, that is the desired behavior with options.

```
# Consider last argument as file path
INPUT_FILEPATH=${*: -1} 
echo $INPUT_FILEPATH

# Process options
while getopts :lq flag
do
case $flag in
l) echo "executing -l flag"
;;
q) echo "executing -q flag"
;;
esac
done
```

Sample execution :

> bash sample.sh /home/username/try.txt

```
/home/username/try.txt
```

> bash sample.sh -lq /home/username/try.txt

```
/home/username/try.txt
executing -l flag
executing -q flag
```